# Can anyone suggest minimum and maximum values that the relative entropy/KL divergence can range when computed from two time-series sequences?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, entropy, information-theory

Can anyone suggest minimum and maximum values that the relative entropy/KL divergence can range when computed from two time-series sequences?

I have calculated the relative entropy for two time-series sequences and it gives me greater than zero values. From the literature, I came to know that relative entropy will never have less than zero value. Moreover, if the value is zero then it suggests that these two time-series sequences are identical.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please add further context, and please incorporate your question into the body of your post.

Comment: My question is how do I interpret the relative entropy values? Like I want to understand that how much one probability distribution (e.g. first time series) differs from another probability distribution (e.g. second time-series). In this case, I have applied relative entropy on these two sequences. Hope this will clear the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [relative entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is always nonnegative. However, it is unbounded: there is no maximum value.

As an extremely simple example, suppose we are looking at two discrete distributions with only two outcomes, where
$$ P(0)=P(1)=\frac{1}{2}, \quad Q(0)=q, \quad Q(1)=1-q \quad\text{for }0<q<1. $$
Then the entropy is
$$ \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} P(x)\log\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} 
= \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\log\frac{1}{2q}+\log\frac{1}{2(1-q)}\bigg)
= \frac{1}{2}\big(-2\log 2-\log q-\log(1-q)\big).$$

And $-\log q-\log(1-q)$ is unbounded for $q$ near $0$ or $1$:

[image: entropy]

R code:

```
qq <- seq(.001,.999,by=.001)
plot(qq,0.5*(-2*log(2)-log(qq)-log(1-qq)),type="l")
```